# onclick value inside loop only works for last value in table

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. I am trying to create a unit conversion calculator. I want to loop through a table x and add an onclick that outputs the *clicked* buttons value.

I've been able to return a NodeList which I am looping through. After I add an onclick. Each button click outputs the value of the last button in the list.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByName("Scalar")

var out = document.getElementById("output")

function Edit(Input){
    out.innerHTML = Input;
}

var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    out.innerHTML = out.innerHTML + x[i].name;
    var b = x[i];
    b.onclick = function() {
        Edit(out.innerHTML + b.value)
    }
    
}
```

```html
<input type = "button" id="Scalar" value = "K" name = "Scalar"/>

<div id="output">

</div>
```

If I click any button my output will be
the value of the last button in the list (DDDDDD)

Comment: Use this.value instead of b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable b is being over written since its in the same code block.
To get correct value use this.value instead of b.value.
Avoid creating a function within a loop, overwriting variables.
Use addeventlistener instead of onclick.
    var x = document.getElementsByName("Scalar")

```
var out = document.getElementById("output")

function Edit(){
    out.innerHTML = this.value
 }

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

   x[i].addEventListener( 'click' , Edit );

 }
```

Comment: Will read up about addEventListener and this, but it works!
Thank you so much. Was driving me crazy, I can finish my assignment now :)